# XMLHttpRequest and Web Workers Access-Control-Origin

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, web-worker

I'm dealing with some Access-Control-Origin issues when using webworkers to make an XMLHttpRequest.

The issue is easily reproducible in this code, main.js:

```
var worker = new Worker('js/createSimplePage.js');
worker.onmessage = function () {
  console.log('message recieved');
};
```

And js/createSimplePage.js:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
    console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=balling&rpp=20&callback=", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
xmlhttp.send();
```

If I include createSimplePage.js in the header of index.html, it runs fine and prints the correct response from the twitter API. However, if I only load main.js and let it try to load createSimplePage.js as a web worker then I receive the error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=balling&rpp=20&callback=. 
Origin file:// is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

A similar error occurs when hosting the files on SimpleHTTPServer except the error is then

```
 "Origin http://127.0.0.1:8000 is not allowed by Access-Countrol-Allow-Origin."
```

I don't understand why loading it as a web-worker would break it so it can't access the API.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think webworkers have the same security level as the browser. Maybe you could ensure you scripts are returned with allow all origins header:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

and probably best to removed your custom header:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
```

This site has more information:
http://enable-cors.org/